I just installed Postgres and Servers column in pgAdmin keeps loading
I just installed postgres in my windows 10 and it is new db to me.
I've restarted the pgAdmin application many times but still it shows the same loading icon on the servers. On the other hand, Shell works fine and commands gets executes in the pgShell.
pgShell
pgAdmin
Can someone please point out the issue and how can I rectify the .

Have you tried connecting to the server (following instructions from pgAdmin documentation)?
